# Tables are politically incorrect. What do we call times tables?

Tags: language, mathematics

[image]

So, at some point, tables (the physical thing) became politically incorrect, and liberals are calling for the offensive term "times table" to be removed from schools. What can we call them instead.

Specifically, it must still be an alliteration. "Times matrices" or "times grids" are a no go.

What can we call them instead of "times tables"?

Comment: I don't know what to say about this except: How this about worldbuilding?

Comment: @Frostfyre It is exactly like [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/what-would-be-a-politically-correct-term-for-hominid/17825). It is world building because this affects my worlds politics.

Comment: That is a _completely_ different question.

Comment: "Politically correct" is an expression. It doesn't have much to do with politics.

Comment: Um, why would the word 'table' become politically incorrect? How do you use the word 'table' in any sort of derogatory way, ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine this in the most politically correct / rage inducing voice:

> It is a *multiplication matrix*, thank you.

Despite the fact that it isn't a mathematical matrix, just a bunch of rows and columns with headings.